# How to update SQL date using NOW()

Tags: php, sql

Basically I have a simple login form. In the database I have a 'last_logged' column and would like to update it with the current date and time every time someone logs in.

I currently have this query:

```
    UPDATE users SET last_logged = "NOW()" WHERE id = 1
```

But it doesn't update the column to the current date. Any ideas why?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? This is a perfectly reasonable question for a beginner programmer.

Comment: @LucM --> perfect example of passive/aggressive comment :p

Comment: @y-b_cause you're right. I deleted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remove the quotes from `NOW()`.  As a function call, it should be unquoted.

```
UPDATE users SET last_logged = NOW() WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Also, some RDMBS use SYSDATE instead of NOW().

Comment: nice :) it worked. something so simple but took me hours to do it! cheers mate

Answer (score 3):

MS SQL uses `GETDATE()` rather than `NOW()`

(Just an FYI)
In `SQL-Server` I now use `SYSDATETIME()`:

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,'19000101',SYSDATETIME()),'19000101');
```

Comment: No, date and time functions are database specific. Whether or not `now()` is valid all depends on their database type (which they did not specify).  I suspect you meant **MS SQL** rather than SQL.

Comment: @Leigh I did mean MS SQL- for what it's worth (-1!) I'll edit my post

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. For some reason SO's not letting me reverse the -1 and locked my vote. Can you try updating the post again?